# Metatags and Commerce - pass taxonomy metatags to commerce product view

Tags: 7, views, commerce, meta-tags

I have a Commerce Product view that pulls in products based on a taxonomy term in the url (category/taxonomy-term).  This is done using relationships.  Ideally, I would be able to edit metatags for each individual term (which I can) and have those metatags populated on the view page (which I can't figure out).

If I create a metatag default for taxonomy term, it works correctly on /taxonomy/term/%tid, but not category/term-name.  If I create a metatag default for that view, I don't have access to the metatags as token replacement values for the term being used.  There is a [metatags:description] token, but it is empty when using it on the view.

Thanks for any direction/insight/help!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the metatag module will provide metatags entered for terms if your view path matches the core taxonomy path (taxonomy/term/%).

In metatag_views_post_render(), metatags checks if your view display path matches the path from the entity's info before it will proceed.

This gives you a couple of options.

1) You can make sure your view uses the taxonomy/term/% path and use Pathauto to make the aliases for your terms for that vocabulary (or all terms) match the desired 'category/term-name' pattern.

2) You can mimic what the metatag module does for your specific view using a custom module and these hooks:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_render().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache) {
  // Build a shortcut to the current display object.
  $display = $view->display[$view->current_display];

  // Only proceed if this view is a full page, don't process block or other
  // Views display objects.
  if ($view->name == 'MY_VIEW_NAME' && $display->display_plugin == 'page') {
    // Check if this is an entity display page, if so trigger
    // hook_entity_view().
    foreach (entity_get_info() as $entity_type => $entity_info) {
      // Entity paths will include an auto-loader that matches the entity's
      // name, thus the path will be 'some/path/%entity_name'.
      if (isset($entity_info['path']) && $entity_info['path'] == 'taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term') {
        // Only proceed if this entity type supports meta tags.
        if (metatag_entity_supports_metatags($entity_type)) {
          // There must be at least one argument and the first argument must be
          // numerical.
          if (!empty($view->args) && is_numeric($view->args[0])) {
            // Only the first argument is used.
            $entities = entity_load($entity_type, array($view->args[0]));
            // Only if the entity actually exists.
            if (!empty($entities)) {
              $entity = array_pop($entities);
              MYMODULE_entity_view($entity, $entity_type, 'full', NULL, TRUE);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view().
 *
 * Provides additional argument to allow the display to be forced, to work
 * around problems elsewhere in the APIs.
 */
function MYMODULE_entity_view($entity, $entity_type, $view_mode, $langcode, $force = FALSE) {
  // Only run this function once per page load.
  static $i_will_say_this_only_once = FALSE;

  // Only proceed if this entity object is the page being viewed.
  if ($entity_type == 'taxonomy_term' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    // Some API calls need to force the data loading.
    if (!$force) {
      // Only run this function once per page load.
      if ($i_will_say_this_only_once) {
        return;
      }
      $i_will_say_this_only_once = TRUE;
    }

    // CTools uses 'page_manager' view mode to indicate the full entity display
    // page rather than 'full', so streamline the internal processes.
    if ($view_mode == 'page_manager') {
      $view_mode = 'full';
    }

    // Generate metatags output.
    if ($output = metatag_generate_entity_metatags($entity, $entity_type, $langcode, $view_mode)) {
      list($entity_id, $revision_id, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);
      $instance = "{$entity_type}:{$bundle}";
      // We need to register the term's metatags, so we can later fetch them.
      // @see metatag_page_build().
      metatag_page_set_metatags($instance, $output);
    }
  }
}
```